# How would I git remote prune just a specific remote branch?

Tags: git, git-remote

One of my coworkers "reused" a branch name, so every time I pull, I get an error message:

```
error: 'refs/remotes/origin/branch' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/branch/subbranch'
...
error: some local refs could not be updated; try running 
 'git remote prune origin' to remove any old, conflicting branches
```

The thing is, I don't want to do a wholesale remote pruning - I'm paranoid, and I want to keep those local references around, in case other coworkers have screwed up in new and interesting ways.

Is there a way I can prune just the offending branch without also pruning all of the other branches which are happily sitting as remote refs on my local repository?

Comment: Have the branches you want to keep around been merged anywhere? If so, there's no need to specifically keep references to them around, you can always get back to those commits. (Even if not, the commits will hang around until garbage collection occurs.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you can specifically delete the local reference branch, if you use the `-r` option of `git branch`:

```
git branch -r --delete origin/branch
```

After this, the new branch can be created appropriately, and fetch and pull happen without errors. (And `git remote prune --dry-run origin` still reports branches to prune.)